# AD7779 ADC Pin Mode Problem

Tags: adc, integrated-circuit, signal, datasheet, signal-processing

I am trying to configure three seperate AD7779's to output continuously at pin mode operation (by using DOUTX pins, not SPI). However, even the decimation rate of 4095 is mentioned at the datasheet at table 1 and table 40, I could not find the MODEX pins combination for the 4095 decimation rate. I really need the parallel output from DOUTX pins so reading via SPI is not an option. Can anyone explain to me how to set up the 4095 decimation rate and what is the appropiate clock divider for DCLK?

datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7779.pdf